# webcam with MJPG image format

Tags: jpeg

I'm working with C# and a usb webcam that supports YUY2 or MJPG image formats.  Thus far I've always had it in YUY2 mode and that works fine.  Recently I tried changing the format to MJPG thinking that it would then feed my program one JPEG image per frame capture.  It appears to *almost* do that.  When I try to display the buffer, my app always takes an exception which is vague, but seems to indicate that the stream is invalid.  I then copied one of the buffers to a file and tried to view it with IrfanView and it tells me that there is no huffman table. Looking at the buffer with a binary editor, I see it does have the SOI and EOF JPEG markers (and several others); however, it doesn't contain a huffman table marker.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?  I've read a bit about JPEG and apparently there are cases where images can use a standard huffman table to reduce file size; however, if that's the case, how do I insert this into the image (if appropriate)?
This is with reference to  Microsoft Lifecam by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the Motion-JPEG standard for AVI files is that a fixed Huffman table will be used so that it doesn't have to be stored in every frame.

Comment: Sorry for the late response; apparently I forgot to check "notify-me-with-responses". :-(  There must then be a way to insert this default huffman table into a JPEG image so that I can view that image right?

Comment: Yes, you can insert a Huffman table into the MJPEG data stream.  All of the JPEG markers are movable and don't use absolute offsets in the file.

Comment: These fixed HT are given in [mmreg.h](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/shared/mmreg.h).